# Can't run nightmare script after switching pc

Tags: node.js, electron, nightmare

I have a script using nightmare and which works on my pc ,and couldnt get it working on another pc.
This is the error im getting :

```
Error: spawn D:\Projects\Lounge\Lounge\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\dist\elect ron.exe ENOENT


at exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
 at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32) 
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16) 
at doNTCallback2 (node.js:439:9)
 at process._tickCallback (node.js:353:17)
 at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:469:11) 
at startup (node.js:134:18)
 at node.js:961:3
```

It seems like its searching for the electron on my pc's path , how could i change it? I have the electron exec , in the node moudle , but the path is diffrent (F:\Lounge\Lounge\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\dist\electron.exe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out why it didn't work.

Nightmare has a native dependency which is installed on the user's home folder.
When i moved the project, i copied only the node_modules folder, and nightmare couldn't find the reconfigured binary path.

In order to solve this, i reinstalled nightmare using npm: `npm install nightmare`, or even better, i created a `package.json` file and stated my dependecies on it, and when i moved over the project (without node_modules), i reinstalled the dependencies using `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running the script from `D:\Projects\Lounge\Lounge`. Try changing directory to `F:\Lounge\Lounge` and run the script.

Comment: I have my project on my USB , so i run it from there , as it's path is F:\Lounge\Lounge

Comment: Try removing the node_modules directory on your usb and run `npm install`